# Breakdown of Analytical Solution to 4th order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem:**

I have the 4th order Ordinary Differential Equation

$$
\frac{\text{d}^4\theta}{\text{d}\eta^4}
+R(\theta-\theta_*)=0
$$

in the interval $0\le\eta\le1$, subject to the boundary conditions

$$
\eta=0: \frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}\eta}=-1 ;
        \frac{\text{d}^2\theta}{\text{d}\eta^2}=0
$$

$$
\eta=1: \frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}\eta}=0 ;
        \frac{\text{d}^2\theta}{\text{d}\eta^2}=0
$$

and where $\theta_*$ is to be determined such that the clamping constraint

$$\theta(\eta=0)=0$$ 
is satisfied. Skipping details, it can be shown that the solution to the differential equation is

$$
\theta=\theta_* + e^{P(\eta-1)}(A\cos P\eta+B\sin P\eta)
+e^{-P\eta}(C\cos P\eta+D\sin P\eta)
$$

where $P=\frac{R^\frac{1}{4}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and (skipping details again) the constants $A,B,C,D$ and $\theta_*$ can be determined from the boundary conditions and constraint. So far, so good.

**The issue:**

The solution works beautifully, until $R$ approaches $10^7$ whereupon it breaks down due to what I believe is the stiffness of the differential equation - the difference between the largest and smallest roots of the characteristic equation is of the order of $2P$ ~$R^\frac{1}{4}$. This is also apparent from the original differential equation itself, where as $R$ becomes very large $\theta \rightarrow \theta_*$ which tends to violate the Neumann boundary condition $\frac{\text{d}\theta}{\text{d}\eta}(\eta=0)=-1$. What I find very odd however, is that the breakdown in the analytical solution is manifested not at $\eta=0$, where the Neumann BC is actually satisfied very well, but by blowing up in the vicinity of $\eta=1$. This is evident in the graphic below:

[image]

**My Question**

Given that the analytical solution tends to break down at large $R$, how much confidence can I place in the computed values in the vicinity of $\eta=0$. The Neumann condition at $\eta=0$ certainly seems to be honoured for $R=10^7$, but I'm a bit circumspect about the correctness of the peak value in the second derivative (right plot in the graphic above).

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Note that in practice, I clamp the value of $\eta$ used to compute $\theta$ and its derivatives at $\eta=1.1-0.1\log_{10}R$, for $R\ge 10^6$

Comment: Out of curiousity: is this equation modelling some real life phenomena (perhaps mechanical bending)? Could it be that for such large values of R the system is better described by another model? Again, I don't doubt that you have considered this possibility and maybe this question is motivated by pure mathematical interest

Comment: It's a model of fully developed natural convection in a vertical enclosure with a constant heat flux on one boundary with the other boundary insulated. The 4th order ODE arises from combining the energy and momentum equations with the Boussinesq approximation.

Comment: Yes, most definitely!!! Thanks for the catch. My LaTeX skills are not what they used to be!!!

Comment: @ Sharat V Chandrasekhar, thank you for the clarification, then I would ask a more concrete question: are you sure Boussinesq approximation is valid for R ~ 10^7?

Comment: What solution method are you using? It should be something like multiple shooting with adaptive segmentation.

Comment: I believe that if the flow can be regarded as incompressible, there is no Rayleigh number limit on the Boussinesq approximation. Now whether the flow remains laminar at $R=10^7$ is a good question!

Comment: @LutzL, I have also used a 4th order Runge Kutta formulation by solving the 2nd Order energy and momentum equations as a system. Here the velocity gradient needs to be an initial guess satisfying the no-slip BC at the other end and it works well, when I supply the analytical solution as the initial guess.

Comment: Its a 4th Order Runge Kutta Fehlberg algorithm embedded in a 2-Dimensional Newton-Raphson wrapper. The 2 a-priori unknown to be determined iteratively are the velocity gradient at $\eta=0$ and $\theta_*$.

Comment: This is single shooting with an explicit method. This is bad for stiff problems. Integrating backward from $η=1$ or integrating from both sides and matching the state vectors in the middle might be a little more stable. Better would be multiple shooting, which is the same with more sub-intervals, and using an implicit method.

Comment: Integrating backwards and using an Implicit RK method are things that are on my task list, but I'll look into the multiple shooting approach as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even simpler solution - balancing the 3$\times$3 system prior to inversion for the coefficients $A,B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 3):

With a proper boundary value solver there is no such boundary layer problem. Using the one from python scipy.integrate the code is

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp, odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def odesys(t,u,R):
    th = u[0]; th_ast = u[4]; 
    return [ u[1], u[2], u[3], -R*(th-th_ast), 0*th_ast]

def boundary(u0, u1):
    return [ u0[0], u0[1]+1, u0[2], u1[1], u1[2] ]

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)

for R in [ 1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6, 1e7 ]:
    res = solve_bvp(lambda t,u: odesys(t,u,R), boundary, x, [-x, 0*x+1, 0*x, 0*x, 0*x-1])
    x_plot = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
    u_plot = res.sol(x_plot)
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.plot(x_plot, u_plot[0], label='R=%.2e'%R)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.plot(x_plot, u_plot[2], label='R=%.2e'%R)
vlabels = [" ", "$\\theta$", "$\\theta''$"]
for k in [1,2]:
    plt.subplot(1,2,k)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("$\eta$")
    plt.ylabel(vlabels[k])
    plt.grid(); 
plt.show()
```

Note that $\theta_*$ was included in the state as a constant function with derivative $0$ so that the bvp solver automatically also adapts this value. This system with now 5 state dimensions allows to give all 5 boundary conditions at once.

The resulting diagram is

[image: plot of 5 solutions]

Comment: Pretty awesome, I now know whom to ask about numerical methods

Comment: Very Nice indeed!! I'm pleased to note that even the broken analytical solution for $R=10^7$ matches the numerical (shouldn't it be the other way around?!)  solution near $eta=0$.

Comment: Also not to be pedantic, but the problem only has 4 Boundary Conditions - the natural boundary conditions are the Neumann BCs at $\eta=0$ and $\eta=1$ where the first derivatives of $\theta$ are -1 and 0, respectively. The condition $\theta(0)=0$ is not a true BC, but a constraint that clamps the solution which would otherwise be non-unique.

Comment: For the extended system of $(θ,θ_*)$ it is a boundary condition and makes the solution unique. This system of a 4th and a first order equation could also be formulated as 5th order equation $θ^{(5)}+Rθ'=0$ where you can now pose all 5 conditions as boundary conditions in the more restricted sense.

Comment: For the extended system, yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to avoid the issue with the breakdown of the analytical solution as follows:

From the constraint $\theta(0)=0)$ we have

$$\theta_* = -(Ae^{-P} +C)$$

and from the no slip condition $\theta''(0)=0$, we have

$$D=Be^{-P}$$

whereupon the remaining boundary conditions yield the following 3 $\times$ 3 system for the constants $A,B$ and $C$

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    e^{-P} &  2e^{-P} & -1 \\
  \cos P - \sin P\ &(1+e^{-P})\cos P +(1-e^{-P})\sin P  & -e^{-P}(\cos P + \sin P)\\
-\sin P & (1-e^{-P})\cos P &e^{-P}\sin P
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} -P^{-1} \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

For very large values of $R$ (large $P$) , the associated very small values of $e^{-P}$ were causing roundoff errors with the default  double precision in the VBA implementation and yielding erroneous evaluations of $B$ and $C$. Assuming a machine roundoff threshold of $10^{-16}$ (typical for double precision), this occurs at a value of $R=7.4\times 10^6$ which ***is just about where I noticed the analytical solution breaking down***! At such low values of  $e^{-P}$, the linear system above is functionally equivalent to

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 &  0 & -1 \\
  \cos P - \sin P\ &\cos P +\sin P  & 0\\
-\sin P & \cos P &0
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} -P^{-1} \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

which gives $C=P^{-1}$, $A=B=0$ which yields the correct solution without any restrictions on $R$ and without recourse to the $\eta$- cutoff hack that I was employing earlier.

So in essence, the solution to the problem that I observed is to just set $C=P^{-1}$, $A=B=0$ for $R>7.4\times 10^6$. As seen in the first graphic below, this does result in any perceptibly abrupt changes in $A$, $B$ or $C$ when this fix is implemented.

[image]

The temperature and velocity profiles now look like this

[image]